# How to stop an Invalid name error?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I try to use my username Tootyfruity and it keeps saying invalid name even though it has online status lit up. any suggestions in how to end this error??

Comment: try deleting and re-typing your name

Answer (score -1):

What I did was changed my name back to Steve and it worked! So Now I can play in my brother and friends world